# How does "enumerate" know when to unpack the values returned?

Tags: python, iterator

Example 1

```
for i, v in enumerate({'a', 'b'}):
    print(i, v)
```

returns

```
0 a
1 b
```

Example 2

```
for x in enumerate({'a', 'b'}):
    print(x)
```

Returns

```
(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
```

But how does `enumerate` know when to unpack the values it returns?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `enumerate`.

Comment: I see well asked question with examples, I don't see any reason to downvote. If someone thinks it should be downvoted, please mention that so OP can improve his question next time.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: your comment amounts to a big "NO!".  Perhaps you could explain what it does have to do with? That would actually be helpful....

Comment: @NedBatchelder I saw that Martijn Pieters ALREADY posted an answer, that's why I didn't edit my comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`enumerate()` knows nothing about unpacking. It is the `for` statement that does this.

The `target` part of the `for` statement acts like a regular assignment does, you can name multiple targets and the right-hand-side value is expected to be a sequence with the same number of elements. `enumerate()` *always* produces a tuple of two elements; your first `for` loop has two targets to unpack it to, the second only has one target.

The principle is the same as if you assigned a tuple to two names:

```
i, v = (0, 'a')
```

vs.

```
x = (0, 'a')
```

See the [`for` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> Each item in turn is assigned to the target list using the standard rules for assignments

as well as the [assignment statements documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), which explains the rules of assignment to target lists:

> Assignment of an object to a target list is recursively defined as follows.
>
> - If the target list is a single target: The object is assigned to that target.
> - If the target list is a comma-separated list of targets: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list, and the items are assigned, from left to right, to the corresponding targets.

When you use *just* `for x in` you have a single target and the `(0, 'a')` tuple is assigned to it. When you use `for i, v in` you have a comma-separated list of targets, the tuple is an iterable with the same number of items as targets, and thus `0` is bound to `i` and `'a'` is bound to `v`.

Comment: It might be worth quoting the simpler (but less rigorous) explanation in the tutorial as well, which IIRC is in the Tuples&Sequences section. It presumably doesn't expect you to understand what an iterable is, etc. (since that all comes later in the tutorial). Although I guess for the 2.x version the reference docs are simple enough to follow.

Answer (score 3):

This is called tuple unpacking and also works in other cases, e.g.

```
a, b = (1, 2)  # a = 1, b = 2
c = (1, 2)     # c = (1, 2)
```

The `for` in your example simply unpacks the tuples of your `enumerate` statement.